# Why does strcpy specifically requires an array as first argument? (As opposed to a char* const ptr)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strcpy, string.h

Isn't an array basically a const pointer to char?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(char* s)
{
    strcpy(s,"ciao");
}

void main()
{
    char str[10]="mamma";
    char * const ptr="papa";

    f(str); // <-- works as expected
    printf("%s\n",str);

    f(ptr); // <-- gives Segmentation fault
    printf("%s\n",str);

}
```

How does strcpy recognize that I provide a pointer and not an array?

I'm aware that strcpy needs enough space in the destination array, but given that this `char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );` is the signature of strcpy, how can I infer that it needs an array as first argument? 
Also, how can strcpy infer it got passed a constant pointer and not an array?

Comment: Indeed. Ptr gets written much lower in memory (closer to 0x00000000) then str[0]. Apparently in read-only memory (text segment). (str[0]) 0x7ffca0bae6ee: 6d 61 6d 6d 61 00 (*ptr) 0x5586fdab8a52: 70 61 70 61 00

Comment: It is not true that `strcpy` requires an array as its first argument.  What `strcpy` requires is a pointer to *writable memory* which is *sufficiently large* to hold a copy of the string pointed to by its second argument.

Comment: To prove that `strcpy` does not require an array, try `char *mptr = malloc(10);  f(mptr);`

Comment: Also, `strcpy` does not "infer it got passed a constant pointer".  It *tries* copying to the pointer you give it.  The segmentation fault happens because the CPU (and/or the MMU) detects that your program is attempting to write to read-only memory.